# Can I auto-collapse OpenUI5 side navigation depending on the screen width?

Tags: sapui5

I am currently using *toolPage* control with *sideNavigation* to display my navigation. By default, its displayed and can be collapsed if I click the "hamburger" icon at the top.

Now, **I would like it to collapse not only by icon-click, but also if the browser width is decreased** (or when a user opens it on the phone). Is there a way to achieve it? I know boolean properties 'sideExpanded' on 'toolPage' control and 'expanded' on sideNavigation control, but how can I set their value automatically depending on the width of the screen?

**Can I see somewhere in the this.getView() structure the actual width of the window?** I assume that then I could tie this expanded value to the function/formatter which determines if the control should be expanded or not. Or should I tie t the devide model somehow? In my manifest.json, I have desktop, tablet and phone deviceTypes defined. What is the correct way to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `sap.ui.Device.resize.attachHandler(myFunction, oListener?)` method, callback function returns parameters `height` and `width` based on your requirement you can expand or collapse the`sideNavigation`.

other way is to check the device `sap.ui.Device.media.attachHandler(myFunction, null, sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD);` using this you can access the callback to with parameters type of device:
Do initialization: `myFunction(sap.ui.Device.media.getCurrentRange(sap.ui.Device.media.RANGESETS.SAP_STANDARD));`

```
function myFunction(mParams) {
switch(mParams.name) {
    case "Phone":
        // Do what is needed for a little screen
        break;
    case "Tablet":
        // Do what is needed for a medium sized screen
        break;
    case "Desktop":
        // Do what is needed for a large screen
}}
```

Regards,
Saddam